# UISegmentedControl get previous selected index

Tags: ios, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a UISegmentedControl with a segmentedValueChanged method on it. 
I need to find out what was the selected index before this method is called . 
How to do this?

Comment: Store it in a property, or subclass UISegmentedControl and override the method when a segment is selected and update a stored value there

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use this function:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger oldSegmentedIndex;
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger actualSegmentedIndex;
.......

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    .......
    self.oldSegmentedIndex = -1;
    self.actualSegmentedIndex = self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
    .......
}
.......
- (IBAction)didSegmentedValueChanged:(id)sender
{
    //Do whatever you want
    self.oldSegmentedIndex = self.actualSegmentedIndex;
    self.actualSegmentedIndex = self.segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to keep a variable that holds the last selected index. Then you just check it's value when you need

Answer (score 2):

There is also a nice solution with **key-value observing**. Here the code for **Swift 3**:

```
class SegmentedControl: UISegmentedControl {

    private(set) var previousSelectedSegmentIndex: Int?

    override func willChangeValue(forKey key: String) {
        if key == #keyPath(selectedSegmentIndex) {
            previousSelectedSegmentIndex = selectedSegmentIndex
        }
        super.willChangeValue(forKey: key)
    }

}
```